# how we can get media files from remote server to Orchard media module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9, orchardcms-1.10

I'm new to Orchard CMS. I was trying to figured out the way to get the Media files from my remote drive into Orchard Media module(On Orchard Dashboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to enable the Upgrade feature, go to Upgrade to 1.x (menu item should be at the top of the left hand menu), click the Media (1.7) tab then click Migrate under Migrating Media Files. This should import all your existing files as Orchard content items.

More detailed instructions can be found here: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dude-where-are-my-images

Comment: Thank you so much.I wasted lot of time on getting media from Server to Orchard UI. This is the simple way.Thanks again.